# window.open not working properly only IE versions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

The following is my code.

```
function a(videoId){
   var width  = screen.width * 0.8;
   var height = screen.height* 0.8;
   var left   = (screen.width  - width)/2;
   var top    = (screen.height - height)/2;

   params  = 'width='+width;  
   params += ', height='+height;
   params += ', top='+top+', left='+left;
   params += ', directories=no';
   params += ', location=no';
   params += ', menubar=no';
   //params += ', resizable=no';
   params += ', scrollbars=yes';
   params += ', status=no';
   params += ', toolbar=no';
   params += ', fullscreen=yes';

   var url ="/static/abc.html?videoId="+videoId;

   var  newwin=window.open(url,'Video Help', params);
   if (window.focus) {newwin.focus()}
     return false`
}
```

In all other browsers new window height and width working as expected.But in IE it's giving full window size(Like f11 mode) I am not able come back from that new window screen.Please help me.

Comment: You say `fullscreen=yes'` ... Giving a size *and* fullscreen is nonsensical, the browser must choose one or the other, and IE just happens to choose fullscreen, and "other browser" just happen to choose the size. There is no "correct" choice.

Comment: I tried with fullScreen =1 also same f11 mode is opening inIE... in rest of the browsers(chrome,safari,Firefox) new window size working properly

Comment: @MaheshG Why are you using the `fullScreen` option at all if you don't want it to be fullscreen??

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe I forgot to remove that param ....now working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN documentation on `window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open):

> fullscreen
>
> Do not use. Not implemented in Mozilla. There are no plans to implement this feature in Mozilla.
>
> This feature no longer works in MSIE 6 SP2 the way it worked in MSIE 5.x. The Windows taskbar, as well as the titlebar and the status bar of the window are not visible, nor accessible when fullscreen is enabled in MSIE 5.x.
>
> `fullscreen` always upsets users with large monitor screen or with dual monitor screen. Forcing `fullscreen` onto other users is also extremely unpopular and is considered an outright rude attempt to impose web author's viewing preferences onto users.
>
> Supported in:
>
> `fullscreen` does not really work in MSIE 6 SP2.

It's all right there. The answer is to not use fullscreen (especially if you don't want the window to be fullscreen).